# Convert Series of TImestamp into Unix Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, how to convert a series of Timestamp in Unix timestamp?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see how it works in python:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = '2019-12-16 12:39:57.633000'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
date.timestamp()
```

and you'll get `1576517997.633`  #note the time now is in epoch such that:

```
GMT: Monday, December 16, 2019 5:39:57.633 PM
Your time zone: Monday, December 16, 2019 12:39:57.633 PM GMT-05:00
```

Seconds, in pandas it works (almost) the same:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':['2019-12-16 12:39:57.633000']})
df['DateTime']=  pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['epoch'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
```